# Enable WPP tracing in a CMake generated Visual Studio project

Tags: cmake, windows-wpp, cmake-generators

I have a C++ dll project, that is generated from a CmakeLists.txt file, that looks something like this (using Visual Studio 2019):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.23)
include(CMakeParseArguments)

project(test_sln)
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "Visual Studio 16 2019")

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

#add files to project
...
#

add_library(test_proj SHARED ${SOURCES})

set_target_properties(test_proj PROPERTIES
    LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
    VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET "WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0"
)
```

I need to enable the WPP tracing setting in the generated .vcxproj file by setting the following options:

```
<WppEnabled>true</WppEnabled>
<WppScanConfigurationData>$(ProjectDir)\trace.h</WppScanConfigurationData>
```

I have tried setting the [VS_SETTINGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/VS_SETTINGS.html) property the following way:

```
set_property(TARGET test_proj PROPERTY VS_SETTINGS "WppEnabled=True")
```

But it ha no effect on the file, as it seems to be able to set metadata only for individual files?
Is there a way to easily set other settings in a .vcxproj file?